# operator<< and std::stringstream reference?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I have a class that holds a reference to a stringstream (used as an overall application log). How do I add text to the referenced stringstream?

An example (as I cannot post actual source here...)
main

```
stringstream appLog;
RandomClass myClass;
.....
myClass.storeLog(&applog);
myClass.addText("Hello World");
cout << appLog.str().c_str() << endl;
```

RandomClass cpp

```
void RandomClass::storeLog(stringstream *appLog)
{
  m_refLog = appLog;
}

void RandomClass::addText(const char text[])
{
  m_refLog << text;    //help here...?
}
```

I'm getting the following error in my real app using a very similar setup and method structure as above.
`error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'std::stringstream *'`
`error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [11]'`

I know the error is because i'm using a reference and still trying to do '<<', but how else am I to do it?  `m_refLog-><<`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De-reference the pointer first

```
void RandomClass::addText(const char text[])
{
    if ( m_refLog != NULL )
        (*m_refLog) << text;    
}
```

In the constructor, initialize the member pointer to stringstream with NULL

```
RandomClass::RandomClass() : m_refLog(NULL) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: better check that it is not null before and inintialize it to null in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `m_refLog` member is a `StringStream *` (i.e. a pointer-to-`StringStream`), not a `StringStream` (or a `StringStream &`.  That is the source of your compile errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer, not a reference. Dereference it to obtain the stream itself.

(Recall that `ptr->foo()` is equivalent to `(*ptr).foo()`.)

I'd also recommend that your functions accept `const std::string&` instead of pointers to C-style `char` buffers.

And the `.c_str()` in your example is redundant.

```
void RandomClass::addText(const std::string& text) {
  (*m_refLog) << text;
}
```